# Jquery Select list items in loop using keyup and key down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to make autosuggest in Jquery,ajax and json to search cities when user register to website.

So far I am able to get results from database.And i appended to list.but now i need to select data using up down and enter keys.

Key down event is adding class to first city. But I want to loop through all results using key up and down and add value to city textbox if user hits enter. I limit data by 5 in php so 5 results are coming in list item.

Here is my code:

```
$('#city').keyup(function (event) {
  var input_query = $(this).val();
  $.post("get_city.php", {
    "query": input_query
  }, function (data) {
    $('#cityres').html("");
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      $('#cityresults').append("<li>" + item.city + "</li>");
    });
  }, "json");
  //below code is for key event
  var key = gtKeycode(event);
  if (key == 40) {
    // I am not sure i need to do this way
    $('li').first().addClass('SelectedCity');
  }
});

function gtKeycode(e) {
  var code;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
  return code;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are **many** ready-for-use autocomplete/suggest plugins, such as the [jQuery UI one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). But if you'd rather develop your own from scratch, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

i think  i have now the solution for your problem hope this will help you..!

1. I made a php file that echo out json encode just list this:

   ```
   //PHP "action.php?action=show"
   e.g $option[] =  array(
     'option0'=>".Choose an option",
     'option1'=>'somepage1',
     'option2'=>'somepage2',
     'option3'=>'somepage3');

   echo json_encode(array('options'=>$option));
   ```
2. I made up html that will be the handler of the output, then will append

   ```
   <select class="myoptions">

   </select> | <span class="optcap"></span>
   ```
3. JS

   ```
   function selectedOption()
   {
     var myoptions = $(".myoptions");
     $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url:'action.php?action=show',
       dataType:'JSON',
       success:function(data){
         if(data.s==1){
           myoptions.empty();
           $.each(data.options, function(x,val){
             myoptions.append("<option class='option' value='"+val.option0+"'>"+val.option0+"</option>"
               +"<option class='option' value='"+val.option1+"'>"+val.option1+"</option>"
               +"<option class='option' value='"+val.option2+"'>"+val.option2+"</option>"
               +"<option class='option' value='"+val.option3+"'>"+val.option3+"</option>");
           });
         }  
       }
     });
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
     selectedOption();
     $(".myoptions").keyup(function(){
       var option = [];

       $("option.option:selected").each(function(x){
         option[x] = $(this).val();
       });
       $(".optcap").html("["+option+"]");
     });
   });
   ```